# Modal issues after upgrading to Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, webpack-2

Due to an upgrade to Webpack@2.7.0 , I had to upgrade Bootstrap (4.0.0-alpha.2 -> 4.0.0) and Bootstrap-loader@2.2.0. In the application, I have a checkbox, which when unchecked should open a modal. I have been using `jQuery('#confirmModal').modal('show')` which was working. But since the upgrade I have noticed that i get `jQuery(..).modal('show') is not a function` error. `jQuery(..).click(function(){})` also does not work, but i don't see an error for that.

This is my `vendor.ts`,

```
import "jquery";
import "jquery-ui";
import "popper.js/dist/umd/popper";
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';
import "hammerjs/hammer.js";
import "bootstrap-loader";
```

Do i need to include something to resolve this issues?

Comment: I would suggest you check out `ng-bootstrap`

Comment: Its clear that there is no element #confirmModal, at time when you calling it..

Comment: @bigless If there is no element created at the time of calling it, how was working prior to the webpack upgrade? Following other articles, I also tried moving `jQuery(...).modal('show')` into `jQuery(document).ready()` , but ended with the error - `jQuery().ready() is not a function`. Does the version of jQuery matter? I am currently on `2.2.2` and haven't upgraded to `3.3.1` because of errors i got with the latest version. Could you please suggest another way I can get this to work without switching to `ng-bootstrap`?